# What's the difference between Character.toUpperCase() and Character.toTitleCase()

Tags: java, character

I was refactoring some of my old code and then I found out that I'd used `Character.toTitleCase()` method at some point and couldn't help myself wondering if `Character.toUpperCase()` would be better.

I read their descriptions and didn't see any basic difference:

> [toUpperCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-)
>
> Converts the character
>   argument to uppercase using case mapping information from the
>   UnicodeData file. Note that
>   Character.isUpperCase(Character.toUpperCase(ch)) does not always
>   return true for some ranges of characters, particularly those that are
>   symbols or ideographs.
>
> In general, String.toUpperCase() should be used to map characters to
>   uppercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over
>   Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can
>   perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M
>   character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot.
>
> Note: This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support
>   all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the
>   toUpperCase(int) method.

and

> [toTitleCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toTitleCase-char-)
>
> Converts the character argument to titlecase using case mapping
>   information from the UnicodeData file. If a character has no explicit
>   titlecase mapping and is not itself a titlecase char according to
>   UnicodeData, then the uppercase mapping is returned as an equivalent
>   titlecase mapping. If the char argument is already a titlecase char,
>   the same char value will be returned. Note that
>   Character.isTitleCase(Character.toTitleCase(ch)) does not always
>   return true for some ranges of characters.
>
> Note: This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support
>   all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the
>   toTitleCase(int) method.

Then I tried to test them like this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {

    String originalString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123546-.,/*&%+";
    StringBuilder upperCaseStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder titleCaseStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++) {
      upperCaseStringBuilder.append(Character.toUpperCase(originalString.charAt(i)));
      titleCaseStringBuilder.append(Character.toTitleCase(originalString.charAt(i)));
    }

    System.out.println("Original String : " + originalString);
    System.out.println("UpperCase result: " + upperCaseStringBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println("TitleCase result: " + titleCaseStringBuilder.toString());
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Original String : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123546-.,/*&%+
UpperCase result: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123546-.,/*&%+
TitleCase result: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123546-.,/*&%+
```

So I couldn't understand the difference between these two methods. As I said before, I used `toTitleCase()` in my code to capitalize a `String`.

Are there any key difference which I didn't consider and which may lead my code to behave other than expected in some special cases?

---

**Note**: *I don't think this is duplicate of [String capitalize - better way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536277/5611328)
. Because in that question the issue is with the performance of string capitalizing, not with the upper and title cases of characters as in this question.*

Comment: Isn't *"If a character has no explicit titlecase mapping and is not itself a titlecase char according to UnicodeData, then the uppercase mapping is returned as an equivalent titlecase mapping."* already clear enough?

Comment: @Tom not for me, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String capitalize - better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536277/string-capitalize-better-way)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Standard ASCII characters are so boring!  Here's something [more exciting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)#In_Unicode):

```
System.out.println(Character.toTitleCase('ǳ'));  // ǲ
System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ǳ'));  // Ǳ
```

[Live demo.](https://ideone.com/w2uesU)

Answer (score -4):

I don't really see any "real" differences here and I think it's best not to overthink small details. I wanna point out this only line here which should help with the "issue" here.

**In general, `String.toUpperCase()` should be used to map characters to uppercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods.**

Documentation `String.toUpperCase()`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

Someone else should comment if they have more inside information.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript.