# Format name in title case Java help please?

Tags: java, string, title-case

so i have to write a java code to :

- Input a name
- Format name in title case
- Input second name
- Format name in title case
- Display them in alphabet order

i know that The Java Character class has the methods isLowerCase(), isUpperCase, toLowerCase() and toUpperCase(), which you can use in reviewing a string, character by character. If the first character is lowercase, convert it to uppercase, and for each succeeding character, if the character is uppercase, convert it to lowercase.

the question is how i check each letter ? 
what kind of variables and strings should it be contained ?
can you please help?

Comment: The `homework` tag is deprecated (you shouldn't use it any longer). I removed it from your question. (You can mention it in the text if you feel it's important for people to know.) For reasons it's deprecated, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `StringBuilder`, whenver dealing with String manipulation.. This way, you end up creating lesser number of objects..

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("rohit");
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("jain");

s1.replace(0, s1.length(), s1.toString().toLowerCase());
s2.replace(0, s2.length(), s2.toString().toLowerCase());            

s1.setCharAt(0, Character.toTitleCase(s1.charAt(0)));
s2.setCharAt(0, Character.toTitleCase(s2.charAt(0)));

if (s1.toString().compareTo(s2.toString()) >= 0) {
    System.out.println(s2 + " " + s1);

} else {
    System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
}
```

Comment: Actually you should use `StringBuilder` unless you need it to be thread-safe - [`StringBuffer` is synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/a/355092/697449).

Comment: Cool +1 for mentioning an optimal way.

Comment: +1 Good solution - don't forget you also need to force the other characters to lowercase!

Comment: how to force the other characters to lowercase? also can it be done without StringBuilder? because I'm in a basic java class and this is the first time we using strings !

Comment: @MohammedAhmed.. I added that code.. See my updated code.. That `s1.replace` and `s2.replace` line..

Comment: @RohitJain i did it, one more question . the names must be entered so how that can be done ? i mean the user who input the names , the names are unknown

Comment: You can ask user to input name.. For that use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) class.. Click on the link to know more about them.. Also, you can search on google by `how to take user input through Scanner`..

Comment: For full international title casing you should actually change the first character to title case rather than upper case. For instance the ǉ character becomes Ǉ in upper case but ǈ in title case.

Comment: @Neil. Yes, but didn't considered Title case here, as OP is still a beginner.. So, might be he'll gradually learn.. But you are right.. So, will update my code, for future reference.. thanks :)

Comment: The answer below from @MadProgrammer is a better option without 2 different inputs..

Comment: ITs full filled my requirements.. thanks man (My requirement was  convert string to Sentence case).

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the first character to uppercase, and then lowercase the remainder of the string:

```
String name = "jOhN";
name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase(); 
System.out.println(name); // John
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I'm assuming OP's reading a single name from the input (first and last), but that would be just a matter of `split`ting the string by `\s` and repeat the process.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just stirring the pot. I read the OP as mean a name (which may contain spaces and possibly even hyphens), but I could just as well be wrong

Comment: In case of full name use tokenizer on space and same logic in while loop with a StringBuilder variable for new name

Comment: Delimiters could be considered as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086123/string-conversion-to-title-case

Answer (score 3):

For traversing Strings using only the String class, iterate through each character in a string.

```
String s = "tester";
int size = s.length(); // length() is the number of characters in the string
for( int i = 0; i < size;  i++) {
    // s.charAt(i) gets the character at the ith code point.
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952363/java-replace-a-character-at-a-specific-index-in-a-string) answers how to "change" a String - you can't. The StringBuilder class provides convenient methods for editing characters at specific indices though.

It looks like you want to make sure all names are properly capitalized, e.g.: "martin ye" -> "Martin Ye" , in which case you'll want to traverse the String input to make sure the first character of the String and characters after a space are capitalized.

For alphabetizing a List, I suggest storing all inputted names to an ArrayList or some other Collections object, creating a Comparator that implements Comparator, and passing that to Collections.sort()... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266827/when-to-use-comparable-vs-comparator) on Comparable vs Comparator.

Answer (score 3):

This should fix it

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    nameList.add(titleCase("john smith"));
    nameList.add(titleCase("tom cruise"));
    nameList.add(titleCase("johnsmith"));
    Collections.sort(nameList);
    for (String name : nameList) {
        System.out.println("name=" + name);
    }

public static String titleCase(String realName) {
    String space = " ";
    String[] names = realName.split(space);
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (String name : names) {
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
            b.append(space);
            continue;
        }
        b.append(name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
                .append(name.substring(1).toLowerCase())
                .append(space);
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` has a method [`toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) that returns a newly allocated `char[]` of its characters. Remember that while `String`s are [immutable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29), elements of arrays can be reassigned.

Similarly, `String` [has a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29) that takes a `char[]` representing the characters of the newly created `String`.

So combining these, you have one way to get from a `String` to a `char[]`, modify the `char[]`, and back to a new `String`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in any number of ways, most of which will come down to the details of the requirements.

But the basic premise is the same.  `String` is immutable (it's contents can not be changed), so you need away to extract the characters of the `String`, convert the first character to upper case and reconstitute a new `String` from the `char` array.

As has already been pointed out, this is relative simple.

The other thing you might need to do, is handle multiple names (first, last) in a single pass.  Again, this is relatively simple.  The difficult part is when you might need to split a string on multiple conditions, then you'll need to resort to a regular expression.

Here's a very simple example.

```
String name = "this is a test";
String[] parts = name.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
for (String part : parts) {
    char[] chars = part.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]);

    sb.append(new String(chars)).append(" ");
}

name = sb.toString().trim();
System.out.println(name);
```