# Why Java Character.toUpperCase/toLowerCase has no Locale parameter like String.toUpperCase/toLowerCase

Tags: java, locale, multilingual, uppercase, lowercase

I am wondering that why `Character.toUpperCase/toLowerCase` has no Locale parameter like `String.toUpperCase/toLowerCase`.

I have to first uppercase of a text that can be in Any language. I have 2 solutions:

1. **Use `Character.toUpperCase`**

   ```
   String text = "stack overflow";
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);   

   sb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0))); // No Locale parameter here.

   String out = sb.toString(); //Out: Stack overflow
   ```
2. **Use `String.toUpperCase`**

   ```
   Locale myLocale = new Locale(locateId);

   String text = "stack overflow";
   String text1 = text.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(myLocale );
   String text2 = text.substring(1);

   String out = text1 + text2; // Out: Stack overflow
   ```

For my Locale. Both way has the same result.

**My question is:**

- Since the text can be in any language. Which way should I use?
- Why `Character.toUpperCase/toLowerCase` has no Locale parameter because there is not much difference between `Character.toUpperCase/toLowerCase` and `String.toUpperCase/toLowerCase` because String is array of Characters.

Comment: Note that the javadoc suggests to use `String`'s version for locale sensitive mappings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`Character#toUpperCase(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28int%29) Javadoc,

> In general, `String.toUpperCase()` should be used to map characters to uppercase. `String` case mapping methods have several benefits over `Character` case mapping methods. `String` case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the `Character` case mapping methods cannot.

So, the answer is your *second* example (`String.toUpperCase`)

Comment: beat me by 6 seconds!

Comment: So I should not use Character.toUpperCase/toLowerCase since my text can be in any language. Thanks!

Comment: Do Character.toUpperCase('i') always run Locale.US or systemLocale? Say running `i -> I` in US locale but turkish gives `i -> \u0130` according to String Javadocs.

Answer (score 7):

As the Javadoc says:

> In general, String.toUpperCase() should be used to map characters to uppercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot.

So use String.toUppercase()

Answer (score 2):

Here I'll explain some of the issues involved with supporting a `ToUpperCase` and `ToLowerCase` version for `char`s, in addition to `String`s, that a locale parameter would not solve:

1. It's possible for an upper- or lower-case version of a `char` to be a string spanning more than one `char`. An example is the German `ß` expanding to `SS` in its upper-case version.
2. A `char` is a 16-bit value, but not all Unicode characters (and not even all Unicode letters) can fit in a 16-bit `char`. Thus, a `char` version of `ToUpperCase` and `ToLowerCase` will not support the entire Unicode character repertoire.
3. Some case mapping conversions (such as the Greek sigma) depend on context; that is, what kinds of characters come before or after the character in question. A `char` version of ToUpperCase and ToLowerCase will not have this kind of context available.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "which method should I use", then this question is a duplicate of [String conversion to Title Case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086123) and the correct answer is EITHER

- Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils.captitalize()` - Javadoc at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html
- Apache Commons Lang `WordUtils.capitalize()` - Javadoc at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html.  This capitalizes each individual word.

If the question is "why doesn't `Character` have locale-sensitive case-changing methods", then the only way you're likely to get an answer is to consult one of the designers of the Java language.  It's unlikely that the Stack Overflow community will be able to give you the answer you want.

Comment: Actually. I have 2 sub-questions as you know. Which way to use - I have the answer from Elliott Frisch and dkatzel. Other question why Character.toUpperCase/toLowerCase has no Locale parameter - I am asking this because maybe there is another reason that Locale is not needed.

Comment: Yes, that "other question" is what my last paragraph addresses.  In future though, if you have two questions, you should ask two questions.  It makes accepting an answer easier, if different answers are "best" for each subquestion.

Comment: Definitely Locale is needed to change the case of an individual character.  For example, the result of converting `i` to upper case is different between English and Turkish.

Comment: Yes. I had the same thought but not sure why Character has no API for it.

Comment: Like my answer says, you'd have to consult one of the designers of Java.  This is beyond the abilities of Stack Overflow to answer.