# How to convert the object into titlecase

Tags: java

Can any one help me how to convert the object in to first letter as capital.
that should  look like..

```
Example: yes 
Expected : Yes.
```

Comment: what object do you mean ?

Comment: Please show the code you have written. We do not do homework or write code for you.

Comment: You need to change a string to have first letter capital?

Comment: `String#charAt` would be a good start, possibly followed by `Character#toUpperCase` and if you want to be really fancy, couple it all together with `StringBuilder` - or you could actually try [goggling](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+proper+case+string) for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Things could be better if you could explain a bit more about the `object` you are talking about however by the example you quoted Take the first letter of the string and then convert it to capital with `Character.toTitleCase(ch)` . 
Refer to the following links for details and please share the object for better explanation [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949170/convert-string-into-title-case)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656941/format-name-in-title-case-java-help-please)
[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086123/string-conversion-to-title-case)

Comment: As explained by @MadProgrammer to in the above comments.