# How do I change the value in "Xxxxx" format even if user inputs like this "xXXxX"? Java

Tags: java

I have a thought:(might too completed)

1. I wonder if I can substring(1) then use .toUpperCase() for the
   string
2. and after that use getLength() to have the length then
   .toLowerCase() the rest in the string

Is there a easier way to do this? So I can have the value stored in "Xxxx" format.
Thank you.

For example: 
No matter user input the value as "hELlo" or "HEllO" , the system always store the value as "Hello". That's may explain my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086123/string-conversion-to-title-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small utility for my self. It might help you. I was sure that my string would always have alphabets in it so did not care about any other characters.  you might want to modify as per your needs.

```
int length = "yourstring".length();/// get the length of the string
        String camelCase = removeCharacters.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();// upper case the first alphabet
        camelCase = camelCase + "yourstring".substring(1, length).toLowerCase();// lowercase all other alphabets
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Apache already comes with this out of the box, and camelCase is different from what OP asked for in his question.

Answer (score 0):

Substring has a one-arg version and a two-arg version. The second argument is non-inclusive. So, the first bit of the string you want is

```
myString.subString(0, 1)
```

and the second bit is

```
myString.subString(1)
```

You can then call the toUpper and toLower methods on the results, and concatenate them.

Comment: That may be true, but he's asking a question to parse user input. It's neither likely to be very long, nor in a critical section. I think it's safe to assume that we can optimise for development time here. :)

Comment: Please see my answer for a more robust solution

Comment: Thank you for noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Apache Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang) project has a [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) class with a capitalize method, as in the following example:

```
WordUtils.capitalize("i am FINE") yields: "I Am FINE"
```

Comment: If I would like to use this method. What package should I import? I'm using blueJay, it says "org.apache.commons.lang3.text" not exist. (import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;)

Comment: Include the commons-lang3 jar on your CLASSPATH and import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils at the top of your file.