# Is there a simple way to convert java string to title case including diacritics, without third party library

Tags: java, string

Is there a simple way to convert java string to title case including diacritics, without third party library.

I have found this old question but I think that Java has got many improvement since.
[Is there a method for String conversion to Title Case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086123/is-there-a-method-for-string-conversion-to-title-case)

**Examples:**

- JEAN-CLAUDE DUSSE
- sinéad o'connor
- émile zola
- O'mALLey

**Expected results:**

- Jean-Claude Dusse
- Sinéad O'Connor
- Émile Zola
- O'Malley

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this method with regex:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(titleCase("JEAN-CLAUDE DUSSE"));
    System.out.println(titleCase("sinéad o'connor"));
    System.out.println(titleCase("émile zola"));
    System.out.println(titleCase("O'mALLey"));
}

public static String titleCase(String text) {

    if (text == null)
        return null;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b([a-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ])([\\w]*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text.toLowerCase());

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    while (matcher.find())
        matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, matcher.group(1).toUpperCase() + matcher.group(2));

    return matcher.appendTail(buffer).toString();
}
```

I have tested with your strings.

Here is the results to output:

```text
Jean-Claude Dusse
Sinéad O'Connor
Émile Zola
O'Malley
```

Comment: Good try but please use a StringBuilder, StringBuffer is overkill here.

Comment: @gouessej good remark, i will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to achieve this -

**Using Apache Commons Library**

```
public static String convertToTileCase(String text) {
    return WordUtils.capitalizeFully(text);
}
```

**Custom function**

```
private final static String WORD_SEPARATOR = " ";

public static String changeToTitleCaseCustom(String text) {
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return text;
    }

    return Arrays.stream(text.split(WORD_SEPARATOR))
            .map(word -> word.isEmpty()
                    ? word
                    : Character.toTitleCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1).toLowerCase()
            )
            .collect(Collectors.joining(WORD_SEPARATOR));
}
```

Calling above custom function -

```
System.out.println(
            changeToTitleCaseCustom("JEAN-CLAUDE DUSSE") + "\n" +
                    changeToTitleCaseCustom("sinéad o'connor") + "\n" +
                    changeToTitleCaseCustom("émile zola") + "\n" +
                    changeToTitleCaseCustom("O'mALLey") + "\n");
```

Output -

```text
Jean-claude Dusse
Sinéad O'connor
Émile Zola
O'malley
```

Comment: You propose 2 answers, the first with a third party library, the second that output 3 wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Big fan of regular expressions, but if anyone want's a different solution, here's mine.
As far as I'm aware, the only split characters should be  , `-` and `'`.

```
public static String toTitleCase(String content) {
    if (content == null || content.isEmpty()) {
        return content;
    }

    HashSet<Character> splitSet = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{' ', '-', '\''}));
    char[] titleCased = new char[content.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
        boolean applyTitleCase = i == 0 || splitSet.contains(content.charAt(i - 1));
        char targetChar = content.charAt(i);
        titleCased[i] = applyTitleCase ? Character.toTitleCase(targetChar) : Character.toLowerCase(targetChar);
    }
    return new String(titleCased);
}
```